# Returning a row more than once in SQL from a single table?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table CUSTOMERS with a key of CUSTOMER_ID. I would like to return multiple rows based on a query:

```
SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID in (130,130);
```

This always returns a single row that matches although I would like it to appear twice.  My motivation is a bit convoluted and far more complex than the tiny example above.  The spreadsheet I would like to cut and paste this information into was the result of a complex join that I do not have access to.  The list that I have has 43,000 records.  I have done this in the past by unloading the row into a file and looping over my input list and grepping the output.  Is there a neat SQL trick I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever logic is generating the "IN (130, 130)" could presumably as easily generate

SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 130
SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 130

which would give it to you twice (and probably be easier to generate).

Comment: What the crap I can just feed it multiply into a csv file or something... this is good.  The other tool has a nice copy and paste area but that is for weinies.

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1:

You can `UNION ALL` your query to itself. That should double the rows.

```
    SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (130,131,...)
UNION ALL
    SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (130,131,...)
```

That ought to do it. I hope you have a good reason for this, because its fundamentally wrong.

### Method 2:

Create a dummy table, with one column and two rows. Join it, without any restrictions, allowing the database to create the Cartesian product:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy ( foo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (2);

SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS JOIN dummy WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (130,131,...)
```

You can use the dummy table with a bunch of values 1..*n* to generate 1 through *n* copies of each row by changing the join criteria/where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
SELECT c.NAME FROM CUSTOMERS c 
JOIN (SELECT 130 AS CUSTOMER_ID UNION ALL SELECT 130) x 
  USING (CUSTOMER_ID);
```

Note that the syntax for selecting without naming a table is vendor-dependent.  The example above works in MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server, for example, but not in Oracle.

You could also store the values `130, 130` as separate rows in a temporary table, and then join the temporary table to `CUSTOMERS`.